# What does "II" mean on micro four thirds lenses?

Tags: lens, terminology, olympus, micro-four-thirds, panasonic-lumix

I've seen micro four thirds lenses listed with the term 'II'. See the below sample listings. What is this term called and why it is used?

[Panasonic Lumix G 20mm f/1.7 II ASPH. Lens](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/986097-REG/panasonic_h_h020ak_lumix_20mm_f1_7_ii_asph.html)

[Olympus M.Zuiko Digital ED 75-300mm f/4.8-6.7 II Lens](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/919786-REG/olympus_v315040bu000_m_zuiko_digital_ed_75_300mm.html?c3api=2572%2C113041916107&gclid=Cj0KCQjwn8_mBRCLARIsAKxi0GLB2JOMIspd-ILOSn2LN9mmFx8aqC3AUmpeumyt5XcmgvzNMuTc4sIaAnM9EALw_wcB&origSearch=Olympus%2075%20300mm%20Ii%20Review%2F%3Fcurrency%3DEUR)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "2nd generation", or "2nd version". Cf. Canon's use of "Mk II" on camera bodies.

Comment: Please do not associate Canon's use of the word "Mark" in the names of camera bodies with any lens naming convention. Canon has never used the word "Mark" in the name of a lens or in the description of a lens. There's already enough misuse of the word "Mark" when describing Canon lenses. There's no need to add more fuel to the fire!

Comment: @scottbb Any idea on where to find the difference between 'II' and 'I'?

Comment: @inckka Not specifically, no. Searching "Panasonic Lumix G 20mm f/1.7 ASPH vs II" yields a few reviews comparing the two lenses. You can also look at the technical specs for each lens at the manufacturer to see if they note any technical differences (number of lens elements, number of groups, etc.).

Comment: @inckka "Any idea on where to find the difference between 'II' and 'I'?" As scottbb suggested, If you search for reviews for each version you can find a site that reviews Camera lens's,  read the review of "I" first and then the review of "II" and the reviewer will usually note the differences between the two. *I realize this comment is unnecessarily redundant.* ;)